# jQuery returned data isn't tidy

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I'm new to using JavaScript so please excuse my bad terminology.

I have a jQuery that is calling an API for a dictionary web service, the whole function works as it should (returning all of the definitions, authors, etc..).

But my problem is that the returned data from the API is coming back in one big block of text and not in a neat format with line spacing between each definition.

If I just search for the URL in a web browser, I get a json response with tidy definitions and spacing.

Here is my search in the service to the API and the data returned.

http://epvpimg.com/MkdEg

Here is the search just using the URL from my code through a web browser (how I think it should look when returned in my web service)

http://epvpimg.com/IWLJf

Has anybody ever seen this problem before or know why, from my code, it is doing so!

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#term').focus(function(){
var full = $("#definition").has("definition").length ? true : false;
if(full === false){
$('#definition').empty();
}
});

var getDefinition = function(){

var word = $('#term').val();

 if(word === ''){

    $('#definition').html("<h2 class='loading'>We haven't forgotten to validate the form! Please enter a word.</h2>");

 } 

else {

    $('#definition').html("<h2 class='loading'>Your definition is on its way!</h2>");

    $.getJSON("http://glosbe.com/gapi/translate?from=eng&dest=eng&format=json&phrase=&pretty=true" +word+ "?callback=?", function(json) {

       if (json !== "No definition has been found."){
           var reply = JSON.stringify(json,null,"\t");
           var n = reply.indexOf("meanings");
           var sub = reply.substring(n+8,reply.length);
           var subn = sub.indexOf("]");
           sub = sub.substring(0,subn);
             $('#definition').html('<h2 class="loading">We found you a definition!</h2><h3>'+sub+'</h3>');

          } 

else {
             $.getJSON("http://glosbe.com/gapi/translate?from=eng&dest=eng&format=json&phrase=&pretty=true" + "?callback=?", function(json) {
                console.log(json);
                $('#definition').html('<h2 class="loading">Nothing found.</h2><img id="thedefinition" src=' + json.definition[0].image.url + ' />');
             });
          }
     });

  }

return false;
};

$('#search').click(getDefinition);
$('#term').keyup(function(event){
if(event.keyCode === 13){
   getDefinition();
}
});

});
```

And the HTML

```
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Matthew Hughes">
    <meta name="Dictionary" content="A dictionary web service">
    <title>Dictionary Web Application</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dictionary.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="top">

            <header>

                <h1>Dictionary Application</h1>

            </header>

        </div>

        <div id="app">

            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a word..." id="term" />
            <button id="search">Define!</button>

        <section id="definition">

        </section>

        </div>

        <footer>

            <p>Created by Matthew Hughes</p>

        </footer>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Your browser is adding the line breaks. JSON does not have formatting.

Comment: Is there anyway of adding the link breaks to my returned data in javascript?

Comment: The original JSON has line breaks, but you're calling `$.getJSON`. That parses the JSON into a Javascript object, which is just data. Then you call `JSON.stringify`, which produces an unformatted JSON string.

Comment: It has to be done through the client in this situation! - I just has to create a client interface and utilise that web service.

Comment: You don't seem to be getting it, you should actually iterate over the parsed object you get, and extract the phrases and meanings, and then output them in the tags you want, not just stringify the object and put it straight out on the page.

Comment: Right, JSON is intended for communication between computers, not for presentation to the user. I hope you're only doing this for development, not the production site.

Comment: This is my first time using Javascript and this project is only for development!

Answer (score 1):

You're providing a third argument to `JSON.stringify`, which pretty-prints the result. So `sub` should have the line breaks you want. The problem is that you're putting it in an HTML document, and HTML automatically merges lines. You can prevent this by using the `<pre>` tag:

```
$('#definition').html('<h2 class="loading">We found you a definition!</h2><br><pre>'+sub+'</pre>');
```

Comment: I changed this line of code and now it doesn't retrieve any data from the API. - Just stays on "Your definition is on its way!"

Comment: This line has nothing to do with retrieving the data, it's just how the result is displayed. You may have typoed something, check your JS console.

Comment: http://epvpimg.com/fJAeb
Looks a hell of a lot better, thank you Barmar!, now just to work out how to remove the indent!

Comment: You asked it to use TAB as the indent with `"\t"`. You can put a number there and it will use that many spaces as the indentation for each level.